# Ck editor not able to delete data when character limit is reached in jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a `textarea` named `PostDesc` for ckeditor.I want to make max length for the characters inside the text area to 5.
I have used the code like following.When the limit is reached,even if I type backspace,delete or cntl+A,it shows me the alert 'Limit reached'.Also the deleted characters are not removing.After this alert,page reloads also.I am unaware why this is happening. Pls help me.My version is ckeditor 3.2.1

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['PostDesc'];
 var description_length = 5;
    if(editor)
    {
       editor.on('contentDom', function()
        {
            editor.document.on('keydown', function( event )
            { 
                 //if not backspace,delete only go inside,but its going inside the condition after limit exceeds  
                if ( event.data.getKeystroke()!=8 || event.data.getKeystroke()!=46 || (event.data.getKeystroke()!=CKEDITOR.CTRL + 65 ))
                    {

                        var data = editor.getData(); 
                        data = $.trim(data.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));  
                        if(data.length>=description_length)
                        {
                            alert('limit reached');
                            var result = data.substring(0,description_length);
                            editor.setData(result);
                            return false;
                        }
                    } 

            }); 
            editor.document.on('paste',function(event)
            {
                //event.preventDefault();     
                        var data = editor.getData(); 
                        data = $.trim(data.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));  
                        if(data.length>=description_length)
                        {
                            alert('limit reached');   
                            var result = data.substring(0,description_length);
                            editor.setData(result);
                            return false;
                        }  
            }); 
        });
    }
```